# Coordinate variation of a Wilson loop

Tags: gauge-theory, chern-simons-theory, wilson-loop

In [Chern Simons Gauge Theory as a String Theory](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9207094), Witten derives the general coordinate variation of a Wilson loop, i.e., equation 3.11. My question is, how does one derive this? I only managed to obtain a similar result by doing a direct variation and integration by parts, the result I obtained had 
\begin{equation}
F_{IJ}=\partial_I A_J-\partial_J A_I.
\end{equation}
This is clearly incorrect, since he specifically says that $F=dA+A\wedge A$.
I believe I am supposed to vary the path somehow, or that the path ordering somehow gives rise to the term $A\wedge A$, which is just the commutator $[A_I,A_J]$. However, I cannot see how this happens.

Comment: This post (v2) is essentially a duplicate of [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65639/2451) Phys.SE question, since Witten's eq. (3.11) is the same as Polyakov's eq. (7.25).